# Зачем нужна функция pygame.init()?

Tags: python, pygame

В [документации](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ImportInit.html) написано:

> This will attempt to initialize all the pygame modules for you. Not
> all pygame modules need to be initialized, but this will automatically
> initialize the ones that do. You can also easily initialize each
> pygame module by hand.

Но что конкретно подразумевается под "инициализацией" не понятно.

Comment: Смотри ответ < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68527294/why-does-pygame-not-run-pygame-init-by-default>